# Use Google APIs to Login with PHP

Tags: php, google-api-php-client

I'm currently building a web app, and I want to log in to the app via Google, much like many other websites (including SO) do. However, I'm having difficulty finding a cohesive tutorial that is current and actually works. I was hoping that you, SO, would have some helpful material to assist me. If you guys have any *actually* useful and cohesive instructions or links to provide, that would be fantastic. Thanks in advance, SO!

EDIT:

So far, I've got a tutorial's code up and running, but whenever I submit it, it seems like it is unable to get an access token. Here ya go:

```
<?php
include_once("config.php");
include_once("includes/functions.php");

//print_r($_GET);die;
echo("output test ");
    if(isset($_REQUEST['code'])){
    $gClient->authenticate();
    $_SESSION['token'] = $gClient->getAccessToken();
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
     $gClient->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

if ($gClient->getAccessToken()) {
    $userProfile = $google_oauthV2->userinfo->get();
    echo("yep ");
    //DB Insert
    $gUser = new Users();
         $gUser->checkUser('google',$userProfile['id'],$userProfile['given_name'],$userProfile['family_name'],$userProfile['email'],$userProfile['gender'],$userProfile['locale'],$userProfile['link'],$userProfile['picture']);
    $_SESSION['google_data'] = $userProfile; // Storing Google User Data in Session
    header("location: account.php");
    $_SESSION['token'] = $gClient->getAccessToken();
} else {
    $authUrl = $gClient->createAuthUrl();
    echo("nope ");
}

if(isset($authUrl)) {
    echo '<a href="'.$authUrl.'"><img src="images/glogin.png" alt=""/> </a>';
} else {
    echo '<a href="logout.php?logout">Logout</a>';
}

?>
```

I have no idea what's really going on, so any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Did you setup the library correctly? Do you have Internet connection? Check the quickstart from the API in Google to get a working example and just keep adding on top of it.

Comment: Okay, I just checked out the quickstart and I think I'll go with that - Thanks!